# Filter email in POSTFIX with PHP

Tags: php, postfix, email-server

I want to create mail server using postfix and i want to create simple scrip using php to filter incoming email. so the diagram is like this :
incoming email-->postfix-->php filter-->postfix-->destination address.
The questions are:
1. How to set up postfix so it will send incoming email to my php script?
2. How to configure php to send back incoming email to postfix after filtering?
Mail server is build in ubuntu 11.04.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html
There is a PHP milter SAPI. (I know nothing about it.)

Answer (score 0):

http://moshez.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/techpostfix-mail-server-filter-email-by.html

**Howto:** create PHP script to filter incoming email on POSTFIX MAIL SERVER

1)you need to create bash script that send the file to the php.

2)the bash script sends the email using "sendmail" command

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! One sure fire way to bring yourself to the attention of the system is to post the same answer to multiple questions. As you appear to be the owner of the target blog I think you should read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Please post a precis of the article and leave the link for details.

Comment: ok i add more details to the answer